# MYSQL Where function

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table made up of `podcasts` I have *done*, *song*, *artist*, *title mix number date* and *etc*. I am using a class with individual methods to display them in separate

My question is, how do you get `desc` rows?  Like this *`(mix_number is an int)`*

```
 select mix_name, date where mix_number = MAX(mix_number) limit 1 //1st query

 select mix_name, date where mix_number = MAX(mix_number - 1)//this would be the second query

 select mix_name, date where mix_number = MAX(mix_number - 2)//3rd query
```

I dont want to hardcode the `where clause` with a number because I want it to update as I add more.

I am really asking is *`MAX(mix_number)`* or *`MAX(mix_number-1)`* proper?  I cant get it to work this way

I hope this is understandable. I have other queries in the methods but an answer here will fix them too.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `desc` rows?  Are you saying you're trying to specifically query the rows with the top N mix_numbers?  Is there a need to query them with separate SELECT statements?

Comment: Yes it was the top N mix_numbes I was going after, not row ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mix_name, date 
FROM tableName
where mix_number = (SELECT MAX(mix_number) FROM tableName)
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
select mix_name, date 
FROM tableName
where mix_number = (SELECT MAX(mix_number) FROM tableName) - 1
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you all, this is the one that worked the best for me. I appreciate all your answers and will keep them all in mind for future use. Thanks again

Comment: Note that this will only work if the mix_numbers are sequential and have no gaps.  If you want the rows for the top N mix_numbers, you should just use `SELECT mix_name, date FROM tableName ORDER BY mix_number DESC LIMIT N` (replacing N with a number), and not do a bunch of separate queries.

Comment: Unfortunately the table is not normalized and you are right. One off number and Im screwed. There are about 10 songs in a row so I ahve to select a query for the tops mix mane and date, as well as all the songs per podcast for the bottom section

Comment: you can order by more than one column, for example: "ORDER by mix_number DESC, date DESC" to order by mix_number primarly, and by date if the mix_number is equal

Answer (score 1):

First query:

```
SELECT mix_name, date
FROM table
ORDER BY mix_number DESC
LIMIT 1, 0
```

Second query:

```
SELECT mix_name, date
FROM table
ORDER BY mix_number DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

If you want all rows from the same query:

```
SELECT mix_name, date
FROM table
ORDER BY mix_number DESC
```

If you want to more precisely sort rows with the same mix_number:

```
SELECT mix_name, date
FROM table
ORDER BY mix_number DESC, date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
select mix_name, date order by mix_number desc
```

Adding `LIMIT  0, 1` will be your first query. `LIMIT  1, 1` will be second. And so on

Comment: If I use the limit when I go to query out the songs for the song query(one you didnt see) then I will only get the first, or second, or 3rd song. So the selectMAX was the best way for me to go

Comment: you may just remove "limit 0, 1" to get all rows